# Looking for the meaning of "stimuscetta"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

I am reading a novel and cannot find the meaning of this word in the dictionary.  It is probably a word from the Milanese dialect : «[È arrivata la stimuscetta.](https://books.google.it/books?id=qmYeszg9AFQC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=stimuscetta&source=bl&ots=qutaSv24l_&sig=ACfU3U3w0BqTaxwyATrQklerYiiKEBMbQQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG7-quuqLrAhVF3KQKHRw5AUY4ChDoATABegQIBBAB#v=onepage&q=stimuscetta&f=false)»

Comment: Which novel are you reading?

Comment: Il gioco della verità di Sveva Casati Modignani (Bice Cairati) who is a Milanese.  The author used that word in another novel.  I assume it’s slang.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Can you please edit your question to add this information?

Comment: You might want add as well that the word itself is in italic in the text, meaning it's not standard Italian.

Comment: It seems to be Milanese, indeed. As you can see in this [document](http://www.sciroeu.it/files/117r.pdf), this word appears in a poem written in Milanese language.

Comment: The Milanese dictionary by Cherubini (available in Google books) doesn't have the term.

Comment: Thank you for the information and also this link on the Academia del dialetto milanese.  That is one of the things I like about the author Sveva Casati Modignani is that she introduces cultural elements that refer to the history and diversity of Italian culture.  I do enjoy reading novels by Domenico Starnone the same way and for similar reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Given that people in the comments assume that it's a word from the Milan dialect, I checked if my Milan dialect dictionary has got the answer.

There's a word "stimiscètta" in the Milan dialect. It's translated as "vagheggino". To know more about vagheggino, I'm inviting you to [the English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vagheggino) or to [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vagheggino/).

Comment: Tuttavia, mi è sembrato di capire che la parola fa riferimento a una ragazza: https://books.google.es/books?id=qmYeszg9AFQC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=stimuscetta&source=bl&ots=qvpaNr14e2&sig=ACfU3U2ajtRdqmtrNZyhXiHXghjVxt4QAQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipk4CU-OT4AhVH3IUKHW5sCZIQ6AF6BAgDEAE#v=onepage&q=stimuscetta&f=false

Comment: In questo [glossario](http://www.milanesiabella.it/glossario_S.htm) appare con il significato di "vanitosa".